Unable to Export Server Certificate with Powershell
When attempting to set up an automated process to update the Octopus Deploy Certificate library with new certificates from our Servers. We are running in the following error message when trying to export the server (iis) certificate when we run our Powershell script through Ocotpus or directly on the server we get an ((E_AccessDenided)) error. We have confirmed that the service account has full admin access on the servers.
NOTE I had to change the server and domain name to "server.company-domain.local" for security.
NotSpecified: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
At C:\Octopus\Work\gzYf58hyUq9kfkEoRV5Bw\Script.ps1:22 char:9
+         Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $certOutputPath
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Octopus\Work\gzYf58hyUq9kfkEoRV5Bw\Script.ps1: line 22
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Octopus\Work\gzYf58hyUq9kfkEoRV5Bw\Octopus.FunctionAppenderContext.ps1: line 258
at <ScriptBlock>, C:\Octopus\Work\gzYf58hyUq9kfkEoRV5Bw\Bootstrap.Octopus.FunctionAppenderContext.ps1: line 2094
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
Found folder for \\company-domain.local\ots\Octopus\Artifacts\certs
Exporting Certificate for server.company-domain.local
Matched a Server Authentication certificate with subject CN=server.company-domain.local
The remote script failed with exit code 1
The action Export Windows Server Cert on SERVER-NAME failed

Note we get the same error when running on the server as Admins.
Powershell Script
$certfilepath = $OctopusParameters['certfilepath']

$certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$serverName = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName).HostName
$certOutputPath = "$certfilepath"


if (Test-Path -Path $certOutputPath) {
    Write-Host "Found folder for $certOutputPath"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Creating Export Folder $certOutputPath"
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $certOutputPath
}

Write-Host "Exporting Certificate for $serverName"
Foreach ($cert in $certs)
{
    if($cert.EnhancedKeyUsageList[0].FriendlyName -ieq "server authentication" -and $cert.Subject.Trim("CN=") -ieq $serverName)
    {
        Write-Host "Matched a" $cert.EnhancedKeyUsageList[0].FriendlyName "certificate with subject" $cert.Subject
        Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath $certOutputPath
    }
}
Write-Host "Confirming if Cert Exported Successfully"
if (Test-Path -Path $certOutputPath\$serverName.cer){
                Write-host "Found certificate in folder."
}
else {
                Write-warning "Certificate not found in folder."
}

We confirmed Local and Domain level admin permissiosn are in place, check if any GPO might be the issue. Confirmed we have the required Powershell Modules, IIS has anonymous authentication enabled
Confirmed Admin rights on Local and Domain level access
Added to Local Server Admin Group
Confirmed all Required Powershell moduels
Confirm no Security or GPO policy is blocking access

Yes the account does have write access to the network drive Found folder for \company-domain.local\ots\Octopus\Artifacts\certs.
What we are seeing is if its creating or exporting its own for example setting the  $certs = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My then run Export-Certificate it works.
So its able to export its own certs but not the Machine (Sever) cert
